# getting disk identifier from the disk name

Tags: bash, label

Is there a way to retrieve the disk identifier from the disk name?
For example I have a disk partition /Volumes/Data and I would like to store the disk identifier in a variable.

Any help?

Comment: Use `df` command and store column1

Comment: @anubhava - that fails if the device is longer than `df`'s column width.  FreeBSD appears to lengthen the line if device names are long, but on a Linux box I have here, `df` splits lines, so more complex parsing is required.

Comment: That's probably true but OP hasn't provided any realistic information in his question to warrant an answer, that's I just left a comment.